# R: Hide worksheet with package xlsx

Tags: r, excel

I've had great success with the R package xlsx for many things.  However, in the documentation, it says "the user has control to set colors, fonts, data formats, add borders, **hide/unhide sheets**, add/remove rows, add/remove sheets, etc."  (Emphasis mine.)

However, I've scoured the documentation and can't find the function to hide sheets.  Can someone point me to it?  Thanks!

Documentation at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf if this helps.

Comment: Don't know. `sos::findFn("xlsx hide worksheet")` returns a set of results that suggest this available is XLConnect:  hideSheet-methods {XLConnect}

Comment: Yes, XLConnect has it.  But XLConnect is in my experience very buggy, whereas xlsx is not, so I was hoping to find an xlsx method.  If no one knows, I may write the package developer.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that others having the same problem can find the answer, here is how developer Adrian Dragulescu replied to my email:

Once you have a workbook

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
```

you can do

```
wb$setSheetHidden(0L, 1L)
```

if you want to hide the first sheet (0-based indexing in Java).
See the documentation here: http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#setSheetHidden(int, int)

I can confirm this works, and many thanks to Mr. Dragulescu.

Comment: I couldn't find `setSheetHidden` in `xlsx` package. is this still working?

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `openxlsx` package:

```
openxlsx::addWorksheet(worksheetName, sheetName, visible = F) #hides
openxlsx::addWorksheet(worksheetName, sheetName, visible = F) #shows (default)
```

More info here: https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/addWorksheet.html